# rich:fileUpload set initial list of files

Tags: file-upload, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I need to initialize an rich:fileUpload component with a default file
I looked at the component's documentation and did not find anything related, in my case i need to show the file only on client-side operation (i already got the file on server-side)
Looking at the component's library i notice that when we click on "add file", the component uses the following syntax to create file on list:

```
$(<component_name>).component.add(this)
```

But i've tried create a class of object with the atributes "fileName", "state" etc (just like the documentation says) and insert when click on js script, but still didn't work.
Anyone has any ideia of how to solve my problem?

Thank's.

PS: I'm using richfaces 3.3.

Comment: You may want to debug the component code to see what's happening. That said the `add()` method expects a file input, not just a file object.

Answer (score 0):

To everyone interested, I could not find a way to insert default file on the component, but i found a workaround for this problem.
I just remove the native list with "listHeight=0" and develop my own list using datatables.